# Register-ObjectEvent `Created` event triggered too early before the file is fully SFTP transferred

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to:

1. Transfer a `zip` file from server *A* to server *B*.
2. Server *B* copies the file into a different folder.

Server *A* transfers the via *SFTP*:

```
Import-Module C:\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Posh-SSH
Set-SFTPFile -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionID -LocalFile $fileName -RemotePath $SftpTarget -Overwrite
```

Server *B* registers a event to unzip the file when the zip file is created:

```
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $filePath Created -SourceIdentifier ListenFileCreated -Action{
    # Copy a zip file
    ....
}
```

My problem is, the `# Copy a zip file` is triggered before the completion of the SFTP transferring. So when I tried to unzip the file I got "File incomplete" exception.

Anyone knows how to setup `Register-ObjectEvent` to only trigger when the file is completed, or other ways to check whether a file is in use?

Comment: That could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958395/copy-file-on-creation-once-complete